# Creating text mosaic in Actionscript

Tags: air, adobe

Does anyone know how to approach creating a text based mosaic using action script given a collection of words?

Similar to this

http://www.ezmosaic.com/mosaic-samples/text-message-mosaic/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by using the text you want to render as a mask for the picture you want to fill the text with.

[Mask property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask)